# is it correct to use th:replace/th:insert without using fragments?

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf, I am wondering if the tags **th:insert** or **th:replace** absolutely need to reference a fragment.

Here is an example, I would like to include the whole page `menu.html` inside the parent template :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <th:block th:replace="child/menu"></th:block>
   </body>
</html>
```

Here is the child menu template `menu.html` :

```
 <ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
 </ul>
```

it works fine, but I don't find any example like this in the documentation, each reference to **th:replace** are called using fragments like this `th:replace="child/menu :: menu"`, so I'm wondering if my code is correct

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. Simple proof is to try to use Thymeleaf expressions within your embeddable page:

```
<ul>
    <li th:text="${attrValue}"></li>
</ul>
```

That works without of problems if you pass `attrValue` model attribute in your initial template. You don't even have to specify Thymeleaf schema URL in your `menu.html` page.

Comment: yes I know it works, I use it currently and there is no error. In the documentation they use `th:replace` systematicaly with fragments, so I was wondering if my code was compliant with the framework and was not a bad practice

Comment: Maybe you should only add `HTML` tag with Thymeleaf schema URL just so Thymeleaf expressions can be recognized by modern IDE's. But I don't see any particular problem in your approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to understand
suppose this the fragment

we are using this in these div

So the final output:

```
 <div id="tagWithFragmentAttribute">
     <div id="contentGoesHere"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="tagWithInsertAttribute">
     <div id="tagWithFragmentAttribute">
      <div id="contentGoesHere"></div>
     </div>
    </div>

    <div id="tagWithIncludeAttribute">
     <div id="contentGoesHere"></div>
    </div>
```